# Finding the kth smallest number where all (hexadecimal) digits are different

Tags: c++, algorithm, bitwise, simd

I'm mostly trying to understand why the simpler `char` array `mask` below (to track which digits have been already used) is much faster than the one 16 bit uint `mask` along with intrinsic ops. On Ryzen 3700x, compiled with "-O3 -march=native", this version takes only 1.02 secs for 10 million calls, whereas the commented out `uint16` `mask` approach takes 2.37 secs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <x86intrin.h>


unsigned int get_digit(unsigned int i, char *mask){
    unsigned int j = 0;
    while(1){
        while(mask[j] == 0) j++;
        if(i == 0) return j;
        i--;
        j++;
    }
}

inline unsigned nthset(uint16_t x, unsigned n) {
    return _tzcnt_u64(_pdep_u64(1U << n, x));
}

uint64_t foo(int i){
    constexpr uint64_t factorials[16] = {1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000};
    uint64_t base = (1ULL<<60);

    // NOTE: Not sure why, but the simpler char array mask below is much faster than the 
    // clever 16 bit mask with intrinsic ops on Ryzen 3700x.

    //uint16_t mask = 0b1111'1111'1111'1111;
    char mask[16] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    uint64_t res = 0;
    int n = 15;
    while(n){
        const unsigned int v = factorials[n];
        const unsigned int d = get_digit(i / v, mask);
        //const unsigned int d = nthset(mask, i / v);
        mask[d] = 0;
        //mask = mask & ~(1<<d);

        i = i%v;
        res += d * base;
        base = base >> 4;
        n--;
    }
    //unsigned int d = nthset(mask, 0);
    unsigned int d = get_digit(0, mask);
    res += d;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Note that "Ryzen 3700x" has the Zen 2 microarchitecture, which had a [notoriously poor pdep/pext implementation](https://uops.info/table.html?search=pdep&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_ZEN2=on&cb_ZEN3=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_doc=on&cb_base=on&cb_bmi=on) (it's good on Zen 3 and newer, and Intel processors)

Comment: You're absolutely right. On a cascade lake cpu, the uint16 version is 4 times faster than char[16]. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`std::uint64_t` is misspelt throughout as `uint64_t` (as if we'd written `using std::uint64_t;` somewhere, but that's not present in the code).

`std::uint16_t` is similarly misspelt.  I don't see a need for exact widths here, so prefer `std::uint_fast16_t` and `std::uint_fast64_t` instead as more portable alternatives.

Why is the function called `foo()`?  That's probably the least informative name possible.  What are we trying to do here?  It needs at least a comment to explain its purpose, but a better name would be helpful.

The other function `get_digit()` appears to have an informative name, but inspection makes me doubt that it's getting one of the digits of `i`.  What's `mask` for?  Perhaps this would be better named.

Overall impression: this code makes no attempt to show what it's for or how to use it.  I would not take on maintenance responsibility for any of it.